# cp command unix error

Tags: unix, command-line-arguments

I am trying to copy files from another user on a server over to my user.

my command is:

```
cp /Directory/*
cp: target /Directory/file1.txt is not a directory
```

What is wrong?
I want to copy all files in the "Directory"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming and also "what's wrong?" is not a sufficient problem description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: You haven't provided a destination, i.e. a target where to put files.

Long answer:

- `cp` needs two or more arguments. All arguments except the last are treated as source, the last is treated as target.
- When you write `cp /Directory/*`, then `/Directory/*` is [expanded](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) to a list of all files in the directory.
- Therefore cp tries to copy all files in the directory, except the last one, into the last one. But that one is not a directory, therefore the command fails.